# Where is the Replace/With list stored?

Tags: macos, keyboard, preferences

This list, the one accessed by System Preferences/Keyboard/Text, vanished when I updated to 10.9.2 (it survived the initial update to Mavericks). I do a lot of writing for the sciences, and I've spent years building that list. (recent MacBook Pro, 10.9.2).

Some sites say I should get the /Users/username/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist file from a backup, but I've searched the HD of my other computer (same specs but running 10.9.1, Replace/With list intact), and I can find no such file.

Other sites say it's in the "NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems array" in 10.9, but unfortunately I don't know what that means. (I'm a user, not a programmer.)

I've heard that it may be linked to Mavericks' new ability to sync this list to iOS devices, but that still doesn't explain why I can't find it on my 10.9.1 machine, which has been syncing to my phone (iPhone 4, iOS 5.x) for years.

Answer (score 6):

In 10.9 the text replacements are also stored in `~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/$USER~*/UserDictionary/local/store/UserDictionary.db`. `UserDictionary.db` is used even if iCloud is disabled and it has precedence over `.GlobalPreferences.plist`.

If you for example run `defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems '({on=1;replace=aa;with=bb;})'` and quit and reopen TextEdit, `aa` is replaced with `bb` in TextEdit, but the changes are reverted if you open the Text tab of the Keyboard preference pane.

You can change both `UserDictionary.db` and `.GlobalPreferences.plist` by using a script like this:

```
date=$(date +%s)
while read -r replace with; do
  plist+="{on=1;replace=\"$replace\";with=\"$with\";},"
  sql+="INSERT INTO 'ZUSERDICTIONARYENTRY' VALUES($((++i)),1,1,0,0,0,0,$date,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,\"$with\",\"$replace\",NULL);"
done < <(sed 's/\\/\\\\/g;s/"/\\"/g' ~/replacements.txt)
sqlite3 ~/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/$USER~*/UserDictionary/local/store/UserDictionary.db "delete from ZUSERDICTIONARYENTRY;$sql"
defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems "(${plist%?})"
```

In 10.8 and earlier versions of OS X the text replacements are stored in the `NSUserReplacementItems` array (not `NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems`) in `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist`.

Comment: How exactly does that script work? How and when should I run it? Can you expand your answer with a few more details on this? I got everything working just like I want by editing the file manually, but like you said, opening System Preferences wipes out my custom items.

Comment: @CodyGray The script reads file _replacements.txt_ in your home directory and inserts replacement definitions from this file both into _.GlobalPreferences.plist_ and _UserDictionary.db_. Each line of the file should contain exactly two words: `what_to_replace replace_with` separated by whitespace.

Comment: This appears to be failing in macOS 10.13 (High Sierra). I'm still hunting for an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

I found an easier way to do it.

Use these steps to export your existing text substitutions:

- Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Text.
- Select the shortcuts you want to export. If you want to export all of your text substitutions, select one of them, then choose Select All from the Edit menu.
- Drag the selected shortcuts to the desktop. This creates a file name Text Substitutions.plist that contains the substitutions you selected.
- Close the System Preferences window.

Use these steps to import the plist file you created in another user account:

- Copy the plist file you previously created to the /Users/Shared/ folder, or to an external drive.
- Log in as the user account where you want to use these text substitutions.
- Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Text.
- Drag the Text Substitutions.plist file to the area of the System Preferences window where the text substitutions are shown (under Replace or With).
- Close the System Preferences window.

source: https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchl2a7bd795/mac

Comment: This is great, and really accessible to the average user. Perfect!

Comment: Here's the terminal version (unofficial)

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/320265/375145

Answer (score 0):

The preferences are stored in NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems in ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist.

You can read the contents by opening the file and looking through it, or by running:

```
defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems
```

To copy your preferences to another machine, take the output of the previous command and run the following command to write your settings:

```
defaults write -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems -array-add '{on=1;replace=foo;with=bar;}'
```

<sup>Replace the contents of the array at the end of the command with the replacements that you want.

`-array-add` appends to the end of the array. Use `-array` to replace the entire array.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your help. You began by saying I can read the contents by opening that file, but I can't find that file. (...and I don't know what "NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems" is...not a GUI item or file/folder heierarchy thing, I assume? A command-line thing in UNIX?)

I’m not comfortable typing in Terminal (I’m a computer user, not programmer), but I have a friend who might be able to come over and help me with that in a week or so. In the mean time, is there a way to find that .plist file using the Finder? 

Thanks again!

Comment: @user72789 Since the file starts with a dot, the file is hidden by default. You need to show hidden files in Finder (`defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool true && osascript -e 'quit app "Finder"'`) or open it through Terminal. NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems is an array *in the file* along with other data. This is why it may not be desirable to copy the entire file, hence my Terminal commands in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a script for backing up and restoring the database. There is no need to extract anything from .GlobalPreferences.plist, just copy the db and open the systeme preferences to reload the settings.

```
############
#!/bin/bash

ME=$USER

DB_BACKUP_DIR=$HOME/Desktop
DB_BACKUP_FILE=$DB_BACKUP_DIR/UserDictionary.db

# Find the path where the replacement DB is:
PLIST=$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.configurationprofiles.user.plist
UUID=$(defaults read "$PLIST" APNSTokens_Production|grep -E '^\s*"[0-9A-F-]*"'|cut -d\" -f2)

DB_RESTORE_DIR=$HOME/Library/Dictionaries/CoreDataUbiquitySupport/$ME~$UUID/UserDictionary/local/store
DB_RESTORE_FILE=$DB_RESTORE_DIR/UserDictionary.db

function Backup(){
    echo "Backup"
    [ \! -d "$DB_BACKUP_DIR" ] && echo "Backup directory does not exist" && echo "$DB_BACKUP_DIR" && exit 1
    echo "Copying database file"
    cp -fv "$DB_RESTORE_FILE" "$DB_BACKUP_FILE"
}

function Restore(){
    echo  "Restore"
    [ \! -r  "$DB_BACKUP_FILE" ] && echo "Cannot read the backup file" && echo "$DB_BACKUP_FILE" && exit 1
    [ \! -d "$DB_RESTORE_DIR" ] && echo "Creating Restore Directory" && echo "$DB_RESTORE_DIR"
    echo "Copying database file"
    cp -fv "$DB_BACKUP_FILE" "$DB_RESTORE_FILE"

    # The database has been copied, but OS X ignores it
    # until the tab System Preferences \ Keyboard \ Text is opened at least once
    # Use osascript to open and close System Preferences \ Keyboard \ Text
    osascript - <<EOC
 tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    reveal anchor "Text" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
    quit
end tell
EOC

}

# Main
case "$1" in
-b)  Backup
     ;;
-r)  Restore
    ;;
 *) echo "Usage: $0 -b|-r"
    echo "\t\t-b: backup"
    echo "\t\t-r: restore"
    exit 0
    ;;
esac
```