# Text shortcuts are constantly erased with macOS Monterey

Tags: shortcut, bug, text-input, monterey

I noticed that with macOS Monterey, my text shortcuts (**System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Text**) can never stay put and are erased every time I add them (not quite sure when, but surely soon after).

Is this known? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Do not know whether to not it's a _bug_ or what, however keep it backed up and you will not have to manually reenter each one of them.

Comment: Good idea of course, and I do that. But it's certainly new behavior, and I was wondering if it's been encountered by others who've figured out how to fix it...

Comment: Are all of them being wiped out at the same time, or just the last one/few you've entered?

Comment: All of them, except for the default one (`omw = On my way!`).

Comment: I can confirm that at least on a reboot they are wiped out and replaced with the default one. There may be other triggers, however I've just started to investigate. So this is definitely a _bug_!

Comment: What's interesting is they are still in the `~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist` _file_ under the `NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems` _key_ but not in the **GUI** and of course do not work.  In other words, starting with them all there and then rebooting only the default one shows, but in **Terminal** the _output_ of `defaults read -g NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems` shows them all. This needs to be reported to **Apple**!

Comment: In case you want to report it yourself, go ahead (no need to attribute me etc.)

Comment: Sorry, but I just do not have the time to report this as I'm now testing how to programmatically and automatically implement a workaround fix, if possible, until **Apple** fixes it. You should report this as it's your question.

Comment: Ah, I don't really want to do that either right now. Definitely write up your workaround in answer once you've got it!

Comment: I get the exact same problem. It's irritating.

Answer (score 1):

I created an account just to share that I found out how to fix this!
It was driving me crazy.

Fix: Make sure you're signed in to your Apple ID. The Monterey update automatically signed me out, and since the **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text shortcuts** are synced up with your Apple ID/iCloud, it wipes them every time you restart the computer because it syncs back to nothing.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same bug in Monterey 12.2.1, i.e., losing text replacements on every boot. Not using iCloud. Worked around by recreating entries, [backing them up, and restoring after reboot](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/back-up-and-share-text-replacements-on-mac-mchl2a7bd795/mac):

**Backup**

1. System Preferences → Keyboard → Text
2. Edit → Select All → drag selected replacements to Desktop ("Text Substitutions.plist" will be created)

**Restore**

1. System Preferences → Keyboard → Text
2. Drag "Text Substitutions.plist" from Desktop into the Text pane

Link courtesy of [Kevin](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/211314/51806). Lri shares a Terminal/script approach and additional details in [his answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127850/51806).